# What's the difference between a[i] , i[a] in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

I write three similar demos and compile them with   `gcc -S 1.c -o 1.s`

these demos ***diff*** in one line :

```
 //  1.c , get 1.s
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 int main()
3 {
4    int a[2]={111,222};
5    int j=0;
6    printf("%d ",0[a]);  // another two are a[j] and j[a]
7    return 0;
8 }
```

I use `vimdiff` to view assemble demo

in .s files, a[j] and j[a] is the same.

there are three different line in 0[a]

```
; main in 0[a] , file 1.s
.loc 1 5 0
movl    $111, -16(%rbp)
movl    $222, -12(%rbp)
.loc 1 6 0
movl    $0, -20(%rbp)
.loc 1 7 0                            
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax              | no these two line  
cltq                                 | in a[j] and j[a]
movl    -16(%rbp,%rax,4), %eax       
movl    %eax, %esi
movl    $.LC0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
```

I learn 8086 and intel assemble last year, several days ago find AT&T and feel a little strange. In 1.s ,`ctlq` extend rax to 64bit , and `$0` doesn't need that. Is that right?

The problem is , after compiled to .s file, a[j] and j[a] is the same,does gcc compiler recognize the base address(pointer a) and the offset (j) ? a and j are both in memory,how can gcc get eax and ebp? Check their type?

Comment: An expression `A[B]` using built-in operator `[]` is equivalent in all respects to `*(A+B)`. The latter is symmetric with respect to `A` and `B` - that's why `B[A]` also works and means the exact same thing.

Comment: You may like the GCC assembly better if you add a couple of options:  `gcc -S -masm=intel -fverbose-asm l.c`

Comment: `gcc -S masm=intel -fverbos-asm ` this parameter is useful ! thanks

Comment: @JohanLundberg This is not a dupe, because symmetry is not guaranteed. Please reopen.

Comment: @einpoklum I said: "An expression `A[B]` using built-in operator `[]` ..." In cases where `A+B` might not be symmetric, a built-in operator `[]` won't be used either.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Right. I missed that.